# Finding those IDs that have retaken 3 distinct courses

Tags: mysql, sql

(I'm new, and apologizes in advance if this is too simple)
So, I'm trying to find those Students who have retaken at least three distinct courses at least once.
I figured that I will have to operate on Takes, and student.

```
Takes(ID,course_id,sec_id,semester,year,grade)
student(ID,name,dept_name,tot_cred)
```

*Both IDs serve as primary keys*

Here are the two solutions I have worked upon;

## 1

```
select student.*
from student, takes
where student.ID = takes.ID 
group by takes.course_id
having count(distinct takes.course_id) <=3 ;
```

## 2

```
select student.*
from student
where 2<= (select takes.ID from takes
        where takes.ID = student.ID 
        group by course_id
        having count(distinct takes.course_id) <=3
        limit 1);
```

*I had to add that limiter because an error kept coming up*

Comment: Your question lacks a question.  What does "retaken" mean in this context?  Why are you not using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (Do they really teach those ancient comma separated, implicit joins in 2020?!?)

Comment: There must be a 3d table that relates Takes with Students. Normally Takes.ID is not related to Student.ID

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And read [mcve] before you start.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Clarification: retaken in this context means; The student should have taken the course at least two times) As for the JOIN syntax, the embarrassing truth is that they are in the next chapter, I haven't reached them yet

Comment: @Reshteen . . . You should tell your instructor/school to use more modern materials.

Answer (score -1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

> Clarification: retaken in this context means; The student should have taken the course at least two times)

If you want students who have taken a single course at least three times, then use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select t.student_id, t.course_id
from takes t
group by t.student_id, t.course_id
having count(*) >= 3;
```

You can use `JOIN` or `IN` or `EXISTS` to bring in more columns from `students` if you like.

Comment: There is no student_id column in Takes.